# Teradata performance impacted due to count distinct

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

There is no join in the query, it is a simple query with two count distinct. But it is consuming more than 9k cpu.

I have taken the necessary stats, but unable to reduce the CPU. please suggest some good methods to reduce the CPU

can you please let me know what is the best way to reduce the impact CPU

Comment: I've never really gotten good at reading Teradata explains, but it looks like the the explain thinks that the actual insert into the destination table is the slowest piece (step 8 in the explain).  Run your select with out the merge into, see how it performs.

Comment: How can i run a select without merge, no idea?

Comment: Just run the select without the insert, see what your CPU usage is then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the target table is a SET table so your query is taking a lot of CPU (duplicate row elimination).

1) Test your select query on a MULTISET table.

```
insert into multiset_table
select count(distinct col1) from source_table.
```

And I believe that your primary index is skewed, the reason for high impact CPU.

2) Make sure your primary index is unique.

```
select hashamp(hashbucket(hashrow(<primary index columns>))), count(*) (bigint) cnt from target_table group by 1 order by 2 desc;
```

If the cnt column is not distributed evenly, then change primary index of the table with more unique columns.

Only 2 things can cause merge to run slow, 
1) Target table is SET table
2) Primary index of the target table is badly skewed